# SQL Server 2019 Ubuntu 20.04 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, tls1.2, ubuntu-20.04, sql-server-2019

After moving our SQL Server database on Ubuntu servers, we're receiving intermittent connection errors from any kind of SQL client / operating system, like the followings:

> - System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient
>   error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the
>   'UseSqlServer' call. ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
> - System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

It happens randomly, at least 1 time an hour.

Software versions on the server side:

- Open SSL: 1.1.1f
- SqlServer 2019: 15.0.4102.2-4
- Ubuntu: 20.04.2

After days of struggling, **we have finally found a workaround** by disabling the TLS 1.2 - and falling back to older versions - in the sql server configuration, which completely eliminates the problem.

In mssql.conf:

```
[network]
tlsprotocols = 1.0,1.1
forceencryption = 0
```

Do you know if there’s a way to make it work without disabling the TLS 1.2?

Comment: Yes, find out why TLS fails and fix the problem. Misconfigured server? Bad client or server certificates? Are you using self-signed certificates perhaps? Have you tried connecting to the server with SSMS or ADS?

Comment: `It happens randomly, at least 1 time an hour.` client/server clocks out of sync perhaps? Check [What role does clock synchronization play in SSL communication](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72866/what-role-does-clock-synchronization-play-in-ssl-communcation).

Comment: For this to occur once an hour instead of all the time, it means that *something* synchronizes the clocks (the normal time sync service?) and something breaks the synchronization (a script meant to "fix" time sync issues by syncing with a different server?)

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks for your replies.
Actually, the clocks seem to be well in sync bewteen the server and the clients.